# How to check if db connection failure in middle of cron execution - ubuntu- php -yii?

Tags: php, yii, cron

I have a cron on ubuntu server, it fetched data from another server (using yii) and make changes in DB. That cron is much time taking.
But today suddenly I faced an issue while running cron

> 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1053 Server shutdown in progress'

But I was unaware about this failure. later while debugging got to know this from error logs.

Is there any possibility where I can

- either shoot and email when such communication link failure is there (through Yii or any other option)
- or any other good suggestion for such scenario?

Anyhow at least I want to know my cron has not ended successfully.

Can we drop an email in Yii for such "'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1053 Server shutdown in progress'" errors?

Comment: Theres a ton of php packages for this, like Monolog.

Comment: yes but again u will have look everyday into logs right?

Comment: Read the docs... Monolog has a ton of transports like smtp, slack and what you wish for. You can even do sms.

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-log-emailtarget

Answer (score 0):

How to email error logs to developer on Yii2 apps? Setup a new target for  the log component besides the `yii\log\FileTarget` that is configured by default:

```
'components' => [
    // ...
    'log' => [
         'targets' => [
             // other targets...
             [
                 'class' => 'yii\log\EmailTarget',
                 'mailer' => 'mailer',
                 'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                 'message' => [
                     'from' => ['log@example.com'],
                     'to' => ['developer1@example.com', 'developer2@example.com'],
                     'subject' => 'Log message',
                 ],
             ],
         ],
    ],
    // ...
],
```

The `EmailTarget` component is another way to log  messages, in this case emailing them via the `mailer` component of the app as specified on the `mailer` attribute of `EmailTarget` configuration. Note that you can also specify messages properties and which levels of messages should be the sent trough this target.

There are other components that represents log targets:

- Telegram: https://github.com/sergeymakinen/yii2-telegram-log
- Slack: https://github.com/sergeymakinen/yii2-slack-log

Comment: Please elaborate more. See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)